# Hibernate AnnotationSessionFactoryBean and Spring 3.0.5

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am getting this error while creating session factory in spring 3.0.5

```
 Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
```

My dispatcher servlet for session factory is given below:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>          
                  <value>com.xxx.csa.entity.UserDetails</value>
                  <value>com.xxx.csa.entity.OperDetails</value>
            </list>
            </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem is with "annotatedClasses". I couldnot identify what the exact problem is. Is there any alternate way for doing this?

Comment: Could you provide the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.csa." />
```

Spring will automatically scan for annotated classes and you can remove the existing reference where you have provided the classes individually from your configuration.